# rails unit test fails although valid data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

I'm new to rails testing and have written a simple unit test to check my validations. I want to check if my sample data is valid and check the name and email field.

bill_test.rb

```
  test "sample data is valid" do
    assert Bill.new(name: bills(:one).name, email: bills(:one).email).valid?, 'Sample data is not valid.'
  end
```

My model:

```
validates_presence_of :name
validates :name, :length => {:maximum => 30 }

validates_presence_of :email
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, :if => :email?
```

after running "rake test:units"

```
  1) Failure:
BillTest#test_sample_data_is_valid [/Users/martinbraun/Documents/Projekte/pay-ma-bill/test/models/bill_test.rb:10]:
Sample data is not valid.
```

My fixture:

```
one:
  name: Hans
  email: hans@gmail.com
```

I also get the failure when removing the validations so I guess the mistake lies in my actual assert. But I cannot see any error there.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[visit this page, it may be helpful for you.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: It rather turned out that fixtures do skip validations in active record. Is that true?
Source: http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/19/testing-series-rspec-models-factory-girl.html